# Grails: Create a select with "jumps" on a range

Tags: grails

What I want:

```
<select ...>
<option ...>0</option>
<option ...>5</option>
<option ...>10</option>
<option ...>15</option>
...
<option ...>1000</option>
</select>
```

I know that by using grails tag `g:select` I can specify `-from="${0..1000}"` - however I can't find any info on the docs on how can I specify "jumps" (not to show option 1,2,3,etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
${(0..1000).step(5)}
```